# How do I get only the last observable output in Angular 6 rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable taking form.valueChanges from different components.

I need the first output to set the toolbar header to visible `window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('showHeader', { detail: true }))`
and after that I need to wait for user input `status`.

This is my challenge: When `status === true` I only want the last observable output (as that contains all form changes). The code shown here works but saves once per observable output.

I have spent hours trawling through the rxjs documentation and answers on SO to no avail. I have tried to switch to Subject but that's clearly not the way to go, several other attempts and now I'm pretty sure(!) that `publishReplay` is the solution but I cannot get it to work.

```
import { debounceTime, publishRelay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Directive, Output, Input, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { SaveService } from './save.service';

@Directive({
    selector: '[save]'
})
export class SaveDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input() public save: any;
    @Output() public appSubmit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    @Input() public debounce = 500;

    constructor(private saveService: SaveService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.save.form.valueChanges
            .pipe(debounceTime(this.debounce))
            // .publishReplay(1).refCount()
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
            if (this.save.valid && !this.save.pristine) {
                window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('showHeader', { detail: true }));

                this.saveService.currentStatus$.subscribe((status: boolean) => {
                    if (status) {
                        this.appSubmit.emit({ data });
                        this.saveService.changeStatus(false);
                        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('showHeader', { detail: false }));
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can the [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html) help?

Comment: Tried that but didn't get any better result (and Subjects are not advised for this kind of Observables (external, hot I believe it is) in several articles). But thx @DavidR

Comment: There is a `takeLast` operator. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeLast

Comment: takeLast operator takes the last value of the output. I want the entire last output only. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     ngOnInit() {
            this.save.form.valueChanges
                .pipe(
debounceTime(this.debounce),
tap((value)=> {
if(!this.status) never();
 else of(value);

}),
mergeMap((value)=>{
return this.saveService.currentStatuss;
})                   

).subscribe(data=> {
this.appSubmit.emit({ data });
                            this.saveService.changeStatus(false);
                            window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('showHeader', { detail: false }));

})
```

you can check in your pipe either you want tp proceed or not. Hopefully, this will help. 
help https://blog.strongbrew.io/rxjs-patterns-conditionally-executing-work/

Comment: Thanks muhamamd-omar-muneer I will see if I can get this working. And thanks for the article link 

Answer (score 0):

Still some details missing but this does the job

```
import { debounceTime, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Directive, Output, Input, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NEVER } from 'rxjs';

import { SaveService } from './save.service';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appSave]'
})
export class SaveDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input() public appSave: any;
    @Output() public submit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    @Input() public debounce = 500;

    constructor(private saveService: SaveService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.appSave.form.valueChanges
            .pipe(
                debounceTime(this.debounce),
                switchMap(data => {
                    if (this.appSave.valid && !this.appSave.pristine) {
                        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('showHeader', { detail: true }));
                        return this.saveService.currentStatus$.pipe(
                            map(status => {
                                if (status === 'save') {
                                    this.submit.emit({ data });
                                    status = 'false';
                                    this.saveService.changeStatus('false');
                                    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('showHeader', { detail: false }));
                                    this.appSave.form.markAsPristine();
                                } else if (status === 'discard') {
                                    console.log('Discarded. Reset form!');
                                    status = 'false';
                                    this.saveService.changeStatus('false');
                                    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('showHeader', { detail: false }));
                                    return NEVER;
                                }
                            })
                        );
                    } else {
                        return NEVER;
                    }
                })
            )
            .subscribe();
    }
}
```